# Energy gap in phonons and violation of perturbation theory

Tags: condensed-matter, perturbation-theory, phonons

In a 1 dimensional chain of similar ions which are connected to each other with similar springs there is just one corresponding frequency for each wave vector.

But solving the problem of one dimensional chain of atoms with two kind of ions with different masses we find that there is two frequencies corresponding to each wave number which we call them optical and acoustic branches. The important fact is that optical phonon's dispersion relation has an energy gap which is not of order of the difference of masses. It means that even an small difference between the masses generates an energy gap in system.

But from the perturbation theory we know that if we take the mass difference arbitrary small it should be possible to find the energy spectrum.And the difference from the equal-mass situation must be small.

What's the problem? Can't we use perturbation theory?

Comment: (I'll presume you mean 'violation' - generally violence only happens when I can't get the perturbation theory to give me the right answer, and the only victim is my pencil point...). Now, have you solved the problem using a 2 atom basis using both the exact same mass, and a slightly different mass? The 2 atom basis is key here.

Comment: @JonCuster Thank you. For similar ions I've solved using the standard method, I labeled each ion's position as x_i . For different masses I categorized each 2 different masses in one "unit cell" and labeled each unit cell with a number, so in the n'th cell there is two ions one is labeled as x_n and another one as y_n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are looking at the gap at the $\Gamma$ point ($k=0$) and not at the real gap at the Brillouin zone boundary. Here is the plot for the phonon dispersion relation of a diatomic linear chain.[image: Phonon dispersion relation of a diatomic linear chain]

You can see that the real gap at the $k=\pi/a$ point is vanishing for $m_1=m_2$.

This plot looks different as typical plots for a monoatomic basis because the definition of the unit cell is different. For a monoatomic basis the primitive unit cell contains only one atom and the unit cell is therefore small, which leads to a larger Brillouin zone. For a diatomic basis we choose a unit cell, which is twice as large and the brillouin zone is half as large. The monoatomic dispersion relation is then folded into the smaller brillouin zone.